# Get HTTPModule's own parameters in web.config?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, arguments, httpmodule

I'm creating an HTTPModule which can be reused a few times, but with different parameters. Think as an example, a request redirector module. I could use an HTTPHandler but it is not a task for it because my process needs to work at the request level, not at an extension/path level.

Anyways, I'd like to have my web.config this way:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <add name="tpl01" type="TemplateModule" arg1="~/" arg2="500" />    
        <add name="tpl02" type="TemplateModule" arg1="~/" arg2="100" />    
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

But most information I could find was [this](http://dailydotnettips.com/2011/05/25/how-to-retrieve-httpmodule-details-from-httpmodulecollection/). I say, yeah, I can obtain the whole `<modules>` tag, but how do each instance of my HTTPModule knows which arguments to take? If I could get the name (`tpl01` or `tpl02`) upon creation, I could look its arguments up by name afterwards, but I did not see any property in the HTTPModule class to get that.

Any help would be really welcome. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: HttpModuleCollection has an AllKeys property. For each key you can Get(key) and check if the return equals your module's this to determine your module's name.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This could be a workaround for your issue.

First, define your module with fields for what you need to set from outside:

```
public class TemplateModule : IHttpModule
{
    protected static string _arg1;
    protected static string _arg2;

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        _arg1 = "~/";
        _arg2 = "0";

        context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(ContextBeginRequest);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Then, from your web app, every time you need to use the module with a different set of those values, inherit the module and override the fields:

```
public class TemplateModule01 : Your.NS.TemplateModule
{
    protected override void ContextBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _arg1 = "~/something";
        _arg2 = "500";

        base.ContextBeginRequest(sender, e);
    }
}

public class TemplateModule02 : Your.NS.TemplateModule
{
    protected override void ContextBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _arg1 = "~/otherthing";
        _arg2 = "100";

        base.ContextBeginRequest(sender, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is just a terrible race condition error waiting to happen. Create a new virtual method in the base class and call that with different arguments from the child classes. Do *not* use static fields to pass arguments, that's silly.

Answer (score 2):

I think, this part of config (system.webServer\modules\add ) is not intended to pass(store) parameters to modules, but to register list of modules to process request.

For possible atttributes in "add" element see - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms690693(v=vs.90).aspx